# How to confirm If current request from EP AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, enterprise-portal

I am sure there will be some helper method/class to confirm whether the current request originated from Enterprise Portal or from Client in AX2012R2. I just cant find it. Can you please point me to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Look in `\Classes\TradeWorkflow`

The method: `activatingFromWeb` will tell you if it is being triggered from EP.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could check if `Global::webSession()` returns a valid object:

```
if (webSession())
{
    // Do some web-specific stuff
}
```